# Avoid repetition of code during data conversion

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have some dummy data like below:

```
data: {
    first: {
        date_2019_01: 10,
        date_2019_02: 15,
        ....
    },
    second: {
        date_2019_01: 30,
        date_2019_02: 35,
        ....
    }
}
```

I have to convert this initial data into following format where date as key is to converted to month and its value as growth.

```
first: [
    {
        month: 1,
        growth: 10
    },
    {
        month: 2,
        growth: 15
    },
    ...
],
second: [
    {
        month: 1,
        growth: 30
    },
    {

    }
]
```

In my solution I get the keys and split it to get my desired month which is pushed to new array. But here my codes are repeated. I am learning on quality of code which includes DRY concept as well.

Please anybody help me write this piece of code in better format.

Thank You.

```
let first = data["first"];

let firstMonth = [];
Object.keys(first).map(function(key) {
    firstMonth.push({
        month: key.split('_')[2],
        growth: first[key]
    });
});

let second = data["second"];

let secondMonth = [];
Object.keys(second).map(function(key) {
    secondMonth.push({
        month: key.split('_')[2],
        growth: second[key]
    });
});

let finalData = {
    first: firstMonth,
    second: secondMonth
}
```

Comment: Can we change the data structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is a `.map` inside a `.reduce`. You can use `Object.entries` instead of `Object.keys` to retrieve both the keys and values at once, which will cut down a bit on the amount of syntax needed:

```js
const data = {
    first: {
        date_2019_01: 10,
        date_2019_02: 15,
    },
    second: {
        date_2019_01: 30,
        date_2019_02: 35,
    }
};
const newData = Object.entries(data).reduce((a, [key, obj]) => {
  a[key] = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, growth]) => ({
    month: Number(key.slice(10)),
    growth
  }));
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to code quality a good way to go is to extract logic into functions with meaningful names. Code has tendency to grow so extracting logic into bits (functions) will have many advantages in future. In my opinion shorter syntax/logic does not always translate to good quality code and in many cases the easily read/understood code even a bit longer is preferable over the short and complicated syntax.

```js
const data = {
    first: {
        date_2019_01: 10,
        date_2019_02: 15,
    },
    second: {
        date_2019_01: 30,
        date_2019_02: 35,
    }
};

function convertMonthData(monthData, resultArr){
    Object.keys(monthData).map(function(key) {
        resultArr.push({
            month: Number(key.slice(10)),
            growth: monthData[key]
        });
    });
}

let convertedMonthData = {};

Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
    const monthData = data[key];
    convertedMonthData[key] = [];

    convertMonthData(monthData, convertedMonthData[key]);
});

console.log(convertedMonthData);
```